# How can I find the advanced settings in my sound properties?

Tags: windows-8, audio

For some reason I can't reach the advanced settings in my audio properties

I don't see the option. The only options I see are:

- general,
- levels and
- a third one

I have a problem with the sound and I need to disable "allow applications to take exclusive control over this device", but I just can't see the option.

I have tried several things, and I am quite sure that I can solve my problem by turning that option off.

I don't understand why I don't see the advanced settings part because I had this problem earlier and I could reach it without a problem.

How do I find this option?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
To use the Microsoft Fix It Utility for "Automatically diagnose and fix Windows audio playback problems" 
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9740814